# JAVA_HOME not set

Tags: shell, java-home

i setup a crontab job to run a php script, 
php ~/Documents/workspace/tools/src/main/php/testcron.php > mylog

and the log file shows: 
JAVA_HOME is not set.

i tried export and saw 
JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/Home"

i changed it to JAVA_HOME="/usr/bin" but if i open other terminal it still showed as 'Library/Java/Home' and also it complain cannot find java_home if i run php script in the same terminal that i changed the JAVA_HOME, anyone know what's wrong? thanks. im using Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should specify your JAVA_HOME  at the beginning of the PHP script or in your cron definition like this : `* * * * * *  export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin;~/Documents/workspace/tools/src/main/php/testcron.php > mylog`

You'd better set your environnement variables in a persistent manner. I'm not used to Mac, so I can't tell you the way to do it, but in Linux, you can set it in config files of shell commands like `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 0):

in crontab add

```
05 * * * * /YOUR_PATH/start.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

in `start.sh` add above everything

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java;
```

Where `/usr/local/java` is where is located java. 
You can use `whereis java` command to lacalize your java.
I suggest you to use absolute path always

ATTENTION: This command starts every 5 minutes, every day!